# Referring to ConfigurationProperties Beans in SpEL expression in @Configuration bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

I have this properties class:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

@ConfigurationProperties("some")
    public class SomeProperties {
        private List<String> stuff;

        public List<String> getStuff() {
            return stuff;
        }

        public void setStuff(List<String> stuff) {
            this.stuff = stuff;
        }    
    }
```

and I enable configuration properties in an @Configuration class like so:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProperties.class)
public class SomeAutoConfiguration {    
}
```

In the same class ("SomeAutoConfiguration") I want to create another bean depending if the list attribute in SomeProperties is empty or not. I thought i could use @ConditionalExpression with the following SpEl:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnExpression("!(#someProperties.stuff?.isEmpty()?:true)")   
    public Object someBean(final SomeProperties someProperties) {
    return new Object();
}
```

The SpEl is correct, but i don't manage to get a hold of the bean containing my properties. Using the above expression i run into

> EL1007E:(pos 43): Property or field 'stuff' cannot be found on
>   null

And trying to get the bean through its name like

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnExpression("!(@'some.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES'.stuff?.isEmpty()?:true)")  
    public Object someBean(final SomeProperties someProperties) {
    return new Object();
}
```

ends up in

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'some.CONFIGURATION_PROPERTIES' is defined

Any ideas? I already tried enabling ConfigurationProperties in another class but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem that you're facing is that `@Conditions` are evaluated when `@Configuration` classes are parsed, so there isn't any guarantee that the `SomeProperties` bean has been defined. Even if it were defined, you probably don't want it to be initialized early so I'd recommend a different approach.

You could try `@ConditionalOnPropety`, that's the annotation that is used internally by Spring Boot whenever it conditionally wants to enable auto-configuration based on a property. If that's not quite flexible enough you can create your own `Condition` and access the `Environment` directly to tell if the property value is empty. If you want to support flexible binding you can use `RelaxedPropertyResolver`. [Here's an example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.0.M1/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/cache/CacheCondition.java).

Comment: Thanks Phil. I think that's exactly what i was afraid off or what i suspected. As i'm trying to write a spring-boot-starter i'm not going to write a custom annotation. The differentiation i want to achieve can be written by plain old Java code. Thanks anyway, more understanding of the mechanism is better understanding :)

Comment: You don't need to write a custom annotation to have a custom condition, you can create create a `SpringBootCondition` class and use it from `@Conditional`. [Here's one example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.3.0.M2/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/EndpointMBeanExportAutoConfiguration.java#L83-L100) from the internals of Spring Boot.

Comment: @PhilWebb I created a custom condition, but the condition is not reevaluated at runtime when I make a call to `/actuator/refresh`. I have the `@Bean` & the containing `@Configuration` classes annotated with `@RefreshScope`. What could be the issue

Answer (score 5):

To complement @PhilWebb answer in regard of Spring Boot 2+, `RelaxedPropertyResolver` has been removed in favor of a more robust alternative named *`Binder`*. Here's a very simple example :

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(JacksonAutoConfiguration.class)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(ObjectMapper.class)
@Conditional(SpringJacksonPropertiesMissing.class)
public class ObjectMapperConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .disable(FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
                .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    }

    static class SpringJacksonPropertiesMissing extends SpringBootCondition {
        @Override
        public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context,
                                                AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
            return new ConditionOutcome(hasJacksonPropertiesDefined(context),
                                        "Spring Jackson property based configuration missing");
        }

        private boolean hasJackonPropertiesDefined(ConditionContext context) {
            return Binder.get(context.getEnvironment())
                         .bind(ConfigurationPropertyName.of("spring.jackson"),
                                                Bindable.of(Map.class))
                         .orElse(Collections.emptyMap())
                         .isEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

**DISCLAIMER**: This code is used to phase out some bad practice regarding jackson object mapper, in order to transition some code to the [spring boot way to configure an object mapper](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper).

Answer (score 1):

Basing on [Brice's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56668992/563175) I made an abstract condition:

```java
public abstract class ConfigurationPropertyCondition<T> extends SpringBootCondition {
    private final Class<T> propertiesClass;
    private final Supplier<T> constructor;
    private final String prefix;
    private final Predicate<T> predicate;

    public ConfigurationPropertyCondition(
            Class<T> propertiesClass, Supplier<T> constructor, String prefix, Predicate<T> predicate) {
        this.propertiesClass = propertiesClass;
        this.constructor = constructor;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        this.predicate = predicate;
    }

    @Override
    public ConditionOutcome getMatchOutcome(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
        return new ConditionOutcome(predicate.test(properties(context)), (String) null);
    }

    private T properties(ConditionContext context) {
        return Binder.get(context.getEnvironment())
                .bind(ConfigurationPropertyName.of(prefix), Bindable.of(propertiesClass))
                .orElseGet(constructor);
    }
}
```

And now I can do something like:

```java
...
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = MY_FEATURE_SETTINGS)
@Bean
public MyFeatureProperties myFeatureProperties() {
    return new MyFeatureProperties();
}
...

@Conditional(MyFeatureConfiguration.MyFeatureEnabled.class)
@Configuration
public class MyFeatureConfiguration {
    ...

    static class MyFeatureEnabled extends ConfigurationPropertyCondition<MyFeatureProperties> {
        public MyFeatureEnabled() {
            super(MyFeatureProperties.class, MyFeatureProperties::new, MY_FEATURE_SETTINGS, MyFeatureProperties::isEnabled);
        }
    }
}
```