# Role names in externalized configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-el

I would like to store role names in application.yml.

But Spring is unable to parse my SpringEl expression. How do I reference property?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = {"/rest/administration"})
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(${roles.admin})")
public class RestAdminController {
```

I am getting error:

> Unexpected token. Expected 'identifier' but was 'lcurly({)'

Comment: Possible related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31500794/referring-to-configurationproperties-beans-in-spel-expression-in-configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also valid authorities in custom bean implementation `@PreAuthorize("@yourBeanName.customMethod(authentication.principal.username)")`

And in the bean you can inject your roles as String and just compare Strings